# Dependent Dropdown using Java script works only on change primary dropdown, It must work on page load if primary dropdown already selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel

I have One Primary drop-down (**Country**) and second dependent `dropdown`.  (**State**). This code works fine only when we select primary `dropdown`. but doesnt work if primary dropdown already selected on page load.

Primary Dropdown Country:

```
<select class="select4" name="country" id="country">
  <option value="">Please Select</option>
     @foreach($country_data as $country)
       <option value="{{$country->country_id}}" {{$profile_data->country == $country->country_id  ? 'selected' : ''}}>{{$country->country_name}}</option>
     @endforeach
</select>
```

Dependent Dropdown State:

```
<select class="select4" name="state" id="state">
  <option value="">Please Select</option>
      @foreach($state_data as $state)
         <option value="{{$state->state_id}}" {{$profile_data->state == $state->state_id  ? 'selected' : ''}}>{{$state->state_name}}</option>
      @endforeach
</select>
```

Java Script code to fill dependent `dropdown`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $('select[name="country"]').on('change', function() {
     var countryID = $(this).val();
        if(countryID) {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'family/state/'+countryID,
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "json",
                success:function(data) {
                    $('select[name="state"]').empty();
                    $.each(data, function(key, value) {
                        $('select[name="state"]').append('<option value="'+ value.state_id +'">'+ value.state_name +'</option>');
                    });

                }
            });
        }else{
            $('select[name="state"]').empty();
        }
    });
});
```

How Ajax code must work on page load also?

Answer (score 1):

You're going to need to manually trigger the change event.

After your:

```
$('select[name="country"]').on('change', function() { ... }
```

Force trigger:

```
$('select[name="country"]').trigger('change');
```

That way when your document.ready function is about to wrap up, you can force trigger the event and if its set, it'll fire the ajax call

Comment: how to write rest code that is in {...}, can you please paste complete code

Comment: Can you be more specific @KapilDevSharma